# Cannot Resolve Symbol Application in android studio

Tags: android

When we write a code color of word 'Application', it changes to red. Can anyone help me out with this?

Here is my build.gradle app

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.nabeel.ask"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 }

 dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
 {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 })
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'


}
```

Comment: Please,

*1. Format your code properly.
2. Mind punctuation and grammar.
3. Take into account language styling, e.g. Java: CamelCase, names of Gradle modules, etc.*

Lastly, try to be as clear as possible in your problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your project

Build>Clean Project/Rebuild project